# Extend session timeout per user in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, session-timeout

I want to change the session timeout per customer. I wanna give the option "Remember me" in the login window. The session for the user who clicks on that should not ever be expired and for others the session timeout should be until the browser gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/02/more-persistent-sessions-in-cake2-x/

using

```
 echo $this->Form->input('auto_login', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'label'=>__('Remember on this computer')));
```